# How to use SSIS using DBAmp?

Tags: ssis, salesforce, dbamp

How can I use SSIS with DBamp to pull salesforce data? What I wanted is to filter salesforce data get it using SSIS and DBAmp.

Comment: Why not use dbamp to pull your salesforce data to a local sql server database, and then uses SSIS on that database.

Answer (score 2):

The [DBAmp Home Page](http://www.forceamp.com) makes it clear that this *should be* achievable:

> SSIS and SSRS Support DBAmp works seamlessly with both SSIS and SSRS. 
>   Use DBAmp and SSIS to construct complex integrations. Build complex
>   reports using any combination of local data, mirrored or real-time
>   salesforce data with DBAmp and SSRS.

So, digging further into their page, [Chapter 5 of the PDF documentation](http://forceamp.com/hats/DBAmpDoc.pdf#page40) has a full section on

> Using SSIS with DBAmp

which includes

> Directly connecting to DBAmp to pull data from salesforce.com

I won't cut and paste the whole chapter here, but it explains how to set up your connection using a `DBAmp OLE DB Provider` and then use an `OLE Data Source` at the start of your SSIS data flow.